# Modify page number position in svmono class

Tags: header-footer, sv-classes

As in the title, I would like to know how I should modify the `svmono` class in order to have the page number centered down (right now they are on the top left/right of the page).

Any feedback will be most welcome.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Don't make any changes to the class file or the layout. Springer alone decides about the layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. However, I don't see what is the problem. I am using it as the ground for a book class. I already looked around on the site and quite some people asked for modifications in order to end up with something like a "mysvmono.cls".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to redefine both the `bchap` and `headings` page styles.

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@bchap{%
  \let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@evenhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\small\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
}

\def\ps@headings{%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\small\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
  \def\@evenhead{\runheadsize\runheadstyle\hfil\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{\runheadsize\runheadstyle\rightmark\hfil}%
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth{%
      {\if@chapnum\thechapter\thechapterend\hskip\betweenumberspace\fi ##1}%
    }{%
      {\if@chapnum\thechapter\thechapterend\hskip\betweenumberspace\fi ##1}}%
    }%
  \def\sectionmark##1{%
    \markright{%
      {\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\z@\thesection\seccounterend\hskip\betweenumberspace\fi ##1}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for. I was just wondering, since this change the overall ratio of the objects in the page, wouldn't it be good to raise the text a bit (to make it look further from the number in the bottom middle, in light of the fact that there is not text anymore above)? Would it be difficult to implement?

Comment: @Kolmin You still have headers. don't you? By the way, I would *never* use `svmono` as a base for my class.

Comment: Now that you ask me this, I realize they are still there, even if there is nothing there (no page anymore and no name or number of the chapter). But maybe the ratio issue is only with what is below. [Concerning the "never", I would say it is a move made out of desperation... :D. As many, I was looking around for a professional, well made, basic template for books, maybe done from memoir, but I did not find anything and I like the overall feeling of svmono. Given this, if you do know a link that does provide that template, it would be great if you would share it.]